# How can I fix the error on my React App after trying to export a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My biggest problem is that I have not been able to get my react app to display since the first week of the course's assignment.  I am at the end of the second week, and have been dealing with this second assignment for several weeks since the course is online through coursera.org.
I have gone over the assignment from week one and watched the videos over and over again, and made many revisions after googling a lot of the answers to the correct code.  I have also gone through the resources of week one that the course offers.

I posted numerous times on week one's discussion board and follow the suggestions given.  I still was not able to get the react app to display, so I moved one the week 2 assignment, and continued working on it.

After more than two weeks of a lot of trial and error and following the error prompts from the visual studio which is the one I am using for this course, I finally started to get some input on what errors I needed to fix on the editor through the cmd window.  Every time I make corrections and run yarn start again, the app started to let me know what I needed to fix on the code.  The following image is the last error that I got.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

This is the code of the functional component that is giving me the error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardTitle, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem } from 'reactstrap';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { DishDetail } from 'reactstrap';
import { Menu } from 'reactstrap';

function RenderMenuItem ({dish, onClick}) {
  return(
    <card>
      <Link to={`/menu/${dish.id}`} > 
         <cardImg width = "100%" src ={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
         <cardImgOverlay>
           <cardTitle>
             {dish.name}
           </cardTitle>
         </cardImgOverlay>
      </Link>
    </card>
  );
}

function Millie  (props) {
  const menu = props.dishes.map((dish)=>{
         return(
           <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
             <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} />
           </div>

           );
           });
          }
      return(
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <Breadcrumb>
              <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/home">Home</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
              <BreadcrumbItem active>Menu</BreadcrumbItem>
              </Breadcrumb>
              <div className="col-12">
                <h3>Menu</h3>
                <hr />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              {menu}
            </div>
            </div>
          );

          
        
export default function Menu(){
  
}
```

Almost all if code has been provided by professor.

[Error page from React App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NljiU.png)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

ty

Mildred

Comment: `export default Millie`

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you're trying to declare something called "Menu" when something called "Menu" already exists.

```js
import { Menu } from 'reactstrap';
```

```js
export default function Menu(){
  
}
```

Either rename the Menu function component or rename the imported one:

```js
// either rename this on import
import { Menu as ReactStrapMenu } from 'reactstrap';

// or call your Menu component something else
export default function MyMenu () {

}
```

As Chris [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64563111/how-can-i-fix-the-error-on-my-react-app-after-trying-to-export-a-functional-comp/64563188#comment114161655_64563188) in the comment below, it seems likely that you don't intend to export the empty Menu function at the bottom at all, and perhaps meant to export your Millie component? In that case, just replace the default export at the end with:

```
export default Millie;
```

Or export it in the same place you're defining it:

```
export default function Millie (props) {
   const menu = props.dishes.map((dish)=>{
   // etc.
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the last part of the code is supposed to be `export default Millie;`

Comment: That would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Mildred! Nice that you're practicing, courses are awesome to learn the basics.

As described in the error you provided, "Menu" is declared twice. If you check the code snippet, you can see that you imported "Menu" from a library, but also declared a function called "Menu".

That is where that error comes from. Just change your default function to any other name, such as "MyMenu"